# Tips or ways to bring out hard-to-hear parts of songs

Tags: ear-training, transcription

I am transcribing some songs to sheet music.  But, I am finding it hard to hear what exactly is being played on lower mixed instruments like rhythm piano or bass drum.  I already have some good techniques for figuring out bass guitar and solos are easy to hear.

Does anybody have any techniques or ways they use to bring up or isolate (to a degree they can hear) parts of songs, e.g. I use a graphic EQ on audacity to bring out the bass or guitar, but there are still some things that I can only just hear.

If anyone cares specifically what song and what I can't hear properly, the song is: King Curtis - *Soul Serenade*, and the parts I can't hear are the bass drum and rhythm piano.  But this isn't that important as I am looking for techniques that will work on more than just this song.

Comment: Eq, including stuff like band-pass filters, is definitely the easiest. But start with the highest-fidelity copy of the audio you can get, and the best hardware. I've been surprised when I listen to songs that I was familiar with at CD quality, through a car stereo, at higher bitrates through good headphones, and hear instruments I never noticed.

Comment: @andy Bonner  ,i don't know much about band-pass filters is there any settings or tips to using it i personally use audacity .do you recommend a different software .and also were do you recommend getting high quality downloads of music i just downloaded the songs i transcribe of youtube ,thanks for your answer it greatly appreciated

Comment: For sure use something better than Youtube. Youtube applies compression algorithms to store the data as efficiently as possible. You could pay for premium tiers of streaming music services to get "high definition audio"; look for 24-bit rather than 16-bit, and either download tracks or make sure you're set to use the highest quality even if network speed is low. [This video](https://youtu.be/2R7qSYa_G8Y) gives a bit of an introduction to filtering in Audacity. "High-pass," "low-pass," "band-pass" and "notch" are just words for which sound you're keeping out and which you're letting through.

Answer (score 5):

Headphones can help, for listening 'through' other instruments in a mix.
I'd be careful about EQing too much, as sometimes the overtones can suggest notes where the fundamentals are hidden.
I've been known to loop one single beat until I could pick out all the notes… in the worst cases by simply hitting every possible note in key until I found matches.

Software such as Izotope RX can separate drums, bass, vocals & 'other instruments' but it's not a surgical scalpel, it's a pretty blunt knife once you get down to the 'other category'.

I worked with a guy who through practise, learned to transcribe full orchestra 4 bars at a time, *down the page* from a portable cassette player [the old piano key type]. He cut his teeth by having to transcribe every song on Top of the Pops every week from the mid 70's until they went to full playback in the 80s. [He got the list of songs Tuesday, the show was recorded with an in-house band on Wednesday, so speed was of the essence]

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, EQ can be very helpful. Sometimes it might be easier to use a low pass, high pass or band pass filter instead of graphical EQ, but it also depends on a specific track.

You can also play with stereo. Often, some instruments are in the center of the stereo image. Most typically vocals, bass, kick drum. You can emphasize them by mixing the track to mono.

If an instrument is panned to the side, you can split the track to separate stereo channels and mute the other channel, or play with the pan slider.

If you split the stereo track to two mono tracks, and invert the phase of one of the channels, you will remove the mono instruments panned to the center, which are often the loudest. Sometimes it may help to slightly adjust the volume of one of the stereo tracks.

Changing the playback speed is another useful trick. Slowing down without changing the pitch may help to transcribe faster sequences. However, changing the playback speed with changing pitch shouldn't be dismissed, as it introduces fewer artifacts. Slowing down a recording by 50% will pitch it down by an octave, which is fine to transcribe high-pitched solo instruments. Less often, one my try to increase the speed, to bring the bass notes to higher, better audible range – but of course this works if the bass line is not too fast.

All the above is possible to do in audacity, or with many other audio editing software.

Playing back the recording at various volumes may help, as the ear frequency sensitivity changes with the volume. Also, it's often easier to hear small details on headphones. Just take care of your hearing and don't listen to the music loud for too long.

Last, but not least, practice. As you transcribe more songs, perhaps also helping yourself with scores, when available, you will get better.

Comment: this is very useful information thank you it has helped alot i have been able to transcribe that part now . do you have any eq ing tips I know eq ing is subjective to each song any transcribing tips is gold to me at the moment thanks

Comment: @jamesrivers I expanded the answer with another trick

Answer (score 3):

Try the free [sonic visualizer](https://www.sonicvisualiser.org/). Use the view which shows frequency vs time. With a little practice you can literally see „the notes“. You can also indicate beats, once you determined the tempo.

Artefacts: Overtones from instruments create a lot of visual noise.

Usually it‘s best to listen to a section and try identifying the corresponding melodies/frequencies, i.e. where they are best to see. Work from there to identify other instruments, e.g. kick drum or bass.

Use SV as an add-on to your proven process of transscribing.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this program, Transcribe!

https://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/overview.html

It has quite a few helpful functions, including reducing the tempo while maintaining pitch.